# Can not load configure property source from config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have an issue related to load configuration property from config-server.
Please you kindly check and advise me how can I load those configure.
Thank you.

JDK: 11
Spring: 2.6.2
Spring cloud: 2021.0.0

**Main**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

/resource/application.properties

spring.application.name=demo
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab.com/mama/test-config-server.git
```

**Git Repo**

```
application.properties
  message="HELLO WORLD"
```

**Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class RestMainController {
    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "------->" + message;
    }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": "59ff5bd35093e6791eb8f6fb7e23d7915b21e565",
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "https://gitlab.com/mama/test-config-server.git/application.properties",
      "source": {
        "message": "\"HELLO WORLD\""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"
```

Comment: You need a spring.config.import property or add spring cloud starter bootstrap

Comment: thank you, it work now

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to keep value for `message` key in "",

```
application.properties
  message=HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: Even if I remove double quote, it's still not work
=>Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"
It seem does not have that property but if I request localhost:8080/demo/default

I can see it show that property.

Do you have any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

on Git, your file name should be demo.properties because you set "spring.application.name=demo".

```java
The HTTP service has resources in the following form:
/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
```

Comment: Hello cherful thank for your comment,
I have update application.properties->demo.properties
but I still can not get  @Value("${message}")

and show the same error use mentioned in question.